# GIMP 2.8.16 unable to open ORA files

Tags: gimp, file-format, open-source, file-conversion, krita

I'm trying to edit/combine paintings I did in Krita with GIMP. Because GIMP can't open .kra files I saved them as .ora files. However, GIMP is unable to open any .ora files, including ones I made using the "Export" option in this version of GIMP.

I run a Windows 10, 64 bit computer. Using GIMP 2.8.16, it has the Open Raster Save & Load plugins.

I get this message: OpenRaster plug-In could not open image

No other info. The best, most recent thing I found regarding this was this: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2016-January/msg01852.html

But I don't know how to read it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use 2.8.16 when 2.8.18 has been available for quite some time?

Comment: Because I was working on a school project & hadn't updated recently. I don't use it super frequently, hadn't used it for months. Therefore, had not updated. Do you know anything about the problem I'm having?

Comment: Also, this question might be more on-topic on SuperUser - but please do not just create another post there, this one could be migrated.

Answer (score 0):

GIMP 2.8.16 was [released in November 2015](https://www.gimp.org/news/2015/11/22/20-years-of-gimp-release-of-gimp-2816/). The change you have linked to is a bug fix to the OpenRaster plug-in. It was done in January 2016 and is thus not included in the 2.8.16 release.

You have two options to get a working plug-in:

1. Change the file-openraster.py file of your current GIMP install as indicated, i.e. remove those lines that have a "-" sign in front of them in the diff shown in the commit message.

or

2. Get GIMP 2.8.18 from https://www.gimp.org/downloads/ - this also includes a fix for [CVE-2016-4994](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2016-4994), which allows [crashing GIMP by crafted XCF files](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767873).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's connected with directory name if it contains non Latin characters, try to move your file on Desktop for example and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and GIMP 2.10.30 installed from the universe repository (`pool/universe/g/gimp/gimp_2.10.30-1build1_amd64.deb`).

The easiest/fastest way I found was to install the flatpak version like this:

```
sudo apt-get install flatpak -y
flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP//stable
```

And .ora files could be read and exported out-of-the-box.

See the full instructions here: https://www.gimp.org/downloads/#linux